# (idk how to explain pls help) how to use the second default value in a function without using the first

Tags: python, function

I'd like to just start by saying I'm completely new to python. I was learning via udemy, and the lesson was on defining functions.

There was a thing where you can give default values in parameters. Idk what it called but when you call the function, the first parameter takes priority??

```
def print_something(name = "someone", age= "unknown"):
     print("My name is", name, "and my age is", age)
print_something(bob)
```

=

```
my name is bob and my age is unknown
```

***MY QUESTION*** is, for the above code, what if I wanted to put the age but no name so it would read out like

=

```
my name is someone and my age is 16
```

Comment: They are called keyword arguments, and `print_something('bob')`, `print_something(age=16)`, `print_something('bob', age=16)`, etc would all be valid calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use a keyword argument :

```
print_something(age=16)
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you can try

```
print_something(age="16")
```